# the easiest solution for a JavaScript/jQuery countdown timer

Tags: javascript, jquery, timer, countdown

I want to implement a countdown timer, that will countdown until a specific date, starting with a date that will be taken form the database.

The countdown timer should not restart at page refresh, it should just countdown until a specific date.

I was wondering if it exists a jQuery or JavaScript open source solution for that?

Comment: @ngduc: what is wrong with that ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here is a great looking countdown timer with a nice tick animation: http://www.littlewebthings.com/2010/02/jquery-countdown-script/

Comment: Nice animation and customizability.

Answer (score 3):

[jQuery Countdown](http://keith-wood.name/countdown.html) is a good one and easy to implement.